# Is there an alternative for using setInterval() for animating fading text in javascript when iterating through objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation, setinterval

I'm currently trying to fade in and fade out text from an array with the help of using the setInterval() function. My init() function loops through the array and calls FadeInThenFadeOut() function to apply fade animations for each object in the array; however, while debugging I noticed that when setInterval() is called, my program iterates to the next object in the array and skips the code to apply the fade animation.

My understanding is that setInterval() delays the callback for applying the fade animation by 50 ms (milliseconds), so I believe this is causing the code to skip. Can anyone please help me find a way to allow my FadeInThenFadeOut() function to complete before iterating to the next object in the array

```js
let quotes = [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "text1",
      "author": "author1"
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "text2",
      "author": "author2"
  },
  {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "text3",
      "author": "author3"
  }
]; 

const quotePlacement = document.createElement('div'); 
quotePlacement.classList.add('text-example');

function init() {

  for(let quoteIndex = 0; quoteIndex < quotes.length; quoteIndex++){

    AssignAndAppendElement(quotes[quoteIndex].text, quotes[quoteIndex].author);  

    FadeInThenFadeOut();

    // now wait for FadeInThenFadeOut() to finish
    // then iterate to the next quoteindex

  }
 
}
 
let elementOpacity = 0; 

const callBackTimeInterval = 50;

function FadeInThenFadeOut() {

  const timerId = setInterval(function() {

    IncreaseOpacity();  

    if(elementOpacity >= 1){
      
      clearInterval(timerId); 
      SetElementVisibility(true); 
       
      FadeOut(); 
      ResetQuotePlacement();
    }
    quotePlacement.style.opacity = elementOpacity; 
  }, callBackTimeInterval); 
 
}

function FadeOut() {

  const timerId = setInterval(function() {

    DecreaseOpacity();

    if(elementOpacity <= 0){
      clearInterval(timerId); 
      SetElementVisibility(false); 
       
    }
    quotePlacement.style.opacity = elementOpacity; 
  }, callBackTimeInterval); 
}

function DecreaseOpacity() {
  elementOpacity -= 0.025; 
}

function IncreaseOpacity(){
  elementOpacity += 0.025;  
}

function SetElementVisibility(visibility) {

  if(visibility){ 
    quotePlacement.style.opacity = 1; 
    elementOpacity = 1; 
    return; 
  }  
  elementOpacity = 0; 
  
}

function AssignAndAppendElement(quoteText, author) {
 
  quotePlacement.innerHTML = "<h1> <q>" + quoteText + "</q> - " + author + "</h1>";
  quotePlacement.style.opacity = 0;

  document.body.appendChild(quotePlacement); 

}

function ResetQuotePlacement() {
  quotePlacement.innerHTML = ""; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap.css"> -->
    <title>Inspirational Quotes</title>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you use css transition ?

Comment: I'm going to try looking into this

Comment: Your title is quite confusing. I hope my answer satisfies you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. You were calling the reset function at the wrong time

```js
function FadeInThenFadeOut() {

  const timerId = setInterval(function() {

    IncreaseOpacity();  

    if(elementOpacity >= 1){
      
      clearInterval(timerId); 
      SetElementVisibility(true); 
       
      FadeOut(); 
      ResetQuotePlacement(); // <---------------- this line
    }
    quotePlacement.style.opacity = elementOpacity; 
  }, callBackTimeInterval); 
 
}
```

If I move it to the `FadeOut` function it works properly

Also, to wait for every fade animation to end you can simply declare a function `showNextQuote` and call that at the end of the `FadeOut` function.

Here is the working code:

```js
let quotes = [{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "text1",
    "author": "author1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "text": "text2",
    "author": "author2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "text": "text3",
    "author": "author3"
  }
];

const quotePlacement = document.createElement('div');
quotePlacement.classList.add('text-example');

function init() {

  showNextQuote();

}

let quoteIndex = 0;

function showNextQuote() {
  if (quoteIndex >= quotes.length) return; //alternatively, set it back to 0 to keep looping
  ResetQuotePlacement();
  AssignAndAppendElement(quotes[quoteIndex].text, quotes[quoteIndex].author);
  quoteIndex++;
  FadeInThenFadeOut();
}

let elementOpacity = 0;

const callBackTimeInterval = 50;

function FadeInThenFadeOut() {

  const timerId = setInterval(function() {

    IncreaseOpacity();

    if (elementOpacity >= 1) {

      clearInterval(timerId);
      SetElementVisibility(true);

      FadeOut();
    }
    quotePlacement.style.opacity = elementOpacity;
  }, callBackTimeInterval);

}

function FadeOut() {

  const timerId = setInterval(function() {

    DecreaseOpacity();

    if (elementOpacity <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      SetElementVisibility(false);
      showNextQuote();
    }
    quotePlacement.style.opacity = elementOpacity;
  }, callBackTimeInterval);
}

function DecreaseOpacity() {
  elementOpacity -= 0.025;
}

function IncreaseOpacity() {
  elementOpacity += 0.025;
}

function SetElementVisibility(visibility) {

  if (visibility) {
    quotePlacement.style.opacity = 1;
    elementOpacity = 1;
    return;
  }
  elementOpacity = 0;

}

function AssignAndAppendElement(quoteText, author) {

  quotePlacement.innerHTML = "<h1> <q>" + quoteText + "</q> - " + author + "</h1>";
  quotePlacement.style.opacity = 0;

  document.body.appendChild(quotePlacement);

}

function ResetQuotePlacement() {
  quotePlacement.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script defer src="main.js"></script>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap.css"> -->
  <title>Inspirational Quotes</title>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively, you could use the css transition property. This makes things quite a bit simpler. Here is a quick example:

```js
const quotes = ["Quote 1", "Quote 2", "Quote 3"];
const el = document.getElementById("holder");
el.style.opacity = 0;

let currentIndex = 0;
let currentShown = false;

const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
  if (currentIndex >= quotes.length) {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    return;
  }
  if (!currentShown) {
    el.style.opacity = 1;
    el.innerText = quotes[currentIndex];
    currentShown = true;
  } else {
    el.style.opacity = 0;
    currentShown = false;
    currentIndex++;
  }
}, 2000);
```

```css
#holder {
  transition: opacity 1.9s;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="holder"></h1>
```

Comment: is that really a setInterval alternative (as PO is asking)?

Comment: If the bug is fixed, (s)he doesn't need an alternative :)

Comment: I don't understand, you mean to ignore his question (present in his title)? Where is the logic?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what he means with that title. I did add a simpler alternative though

Answer (score -1):

css method, with [animationend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/animationend_event)  **and no use of setInterval()**

I used the standard html method for quotes with auth.

the loop is restarted on the next element as soon as the animationend event occurs

```js
const DomParser = new DOMParser()
const quotes = 
    [ { id: 1, text: 'text1', author: 'author1' } 
    , { id: 2, text: 'text2', author: 'author2' } 
    , { id: 3, text: 'text3', author: 'author3' } 
    ] 
const quotePlacement = document.createElement('div')
      quotePlacement.index = -1

function newQuote(txt,auth)
  {
  let elm = `<blockquote>
              <p>${txt}</p>
              <footer>${auth}</footer>
             </blockquote>`
  return DomParser.parseFromString( elm, 'text/html').body.firstChild
  }
function nextQuoteLoop()
  {
  quotePlacement.index = ++quotePlacement.index % quotes.length
  let { text, author } = quotes[quotePlacement.index]
  if (quotePlacement.firstChild) 
    { quotePlacement.firstChild.remove() }
  quotePlacement.appendChild( newQuote(text,author ))
  quotePlacement.firstChild.classList.add('fade-in-out')
  }

// main
document.body.appendChild(quotePlacement)
quotePlacement.onanimationend = nextQuoteLoop 

nextQuoteLoop() // start the first one...
```

```css
.fade-in-out  { animation: fadeInOut ease 7s; }
@keyframes fadeInOut {
  0%   { opacity:0; }
  50%  { opacity:1; }
  100% { opacity:0; }
}

/* classic blockquote */
blockquote {
  padding: 6px 16px;
  border: none;
  quotes: "\201C\2009" "\2009\201D";
  display: block;
  float: right;
  opacity:0; 
}
blockquote p { 
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 0 16px 0 0;
  text-indent: -12px;
  color: #251487;     
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
}
blockquote p:before {
  content: open-quote;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 32px;
}
blockquote p:after {
  content: close-quote;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 32px;
}
blockquote footer {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .7em;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #2d0068;
}
```

Comment: I imagine that it will be impossible to have a rational explanation for this downvote...